# how to return result from blobService.getBlobToStream in node.js?

Tags: node.js, azure-storage

I am trying to get an excel stored in azure blob. I am successful in reading the file into a file '**testing.xlsx**'. Now, I want to use this excel file ('**testing.xlsx**') out of `blobService.getBlobToStream()`, but unable to do it.

```
blobService.getBlobToStream(container, blobname, fs.createWriteStream('testing.xlsx'), function (error, result) {
              if(!error) {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write a sample code with the node package [`azure-storage`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-storage) as below, then run it successfully without any error to download my blob to an excel file `testing.xlsx`.

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var fs = require('fs');
var accountName = '<storage account name>';
var accountKey = '<storage account key>';
var blobService = azure.createBlobService(accountName, accountKey);

var containerName = 'test';
var blobName = 'testing.xlsx';
var localFileName = 'testing.xlsx';

var writable = fs.createWriteStream(localFileName);
blobService.getBlobToStream(containerName, blobName, writable, function(error, result) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }else{
        console.log(result)
    }
})
```

Its result and the screenshot are as below.

[image]

[image]

So I don't know what issue you got. If any error information you got or other else, please update your post to let me know for helping.

---

Update:

```
var writable = fs.createWriteStream(localFileName);
blobService.getBlobToStream(containerName, blobName, writable, function(error, result) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }else{
        console.log(result)
    }
    fs.readFile(localFileName, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
        console.log(data);
    });
})
```

[image]

Comment: i am also able to download the Blob into .xlsx file. My concern is that i am not able to access those data stored in .xlsx file outside  blobService.getBlobToStream(). if i try to print the content of .xlsx file it shows null